# Setting up a queue using times in R

Tags: r, time, count, queue

I am trying to figure out how to set up a queue based on arrival and call times. Basically I want a column that shows the number of people in line at that moment. I want to be able to add 1 when a person arrives and subtract 1 when a person is called. Any ideas on how to do this? Preferably without relying on loops. Below is the first 20 lines of the data:

```
    df[1:20,]
   Date_of_Service Ticket Arrival_Time Call_Time
1       09/01/2015      1      6:40:04   7:31:09
2       09/01/2015      2      6:59:14   7:32:24
3       09/01/2015      3      6:59:36   7:33:47
4       09/01/2015      4      7:00:16   7:30:04
5       09/01/2015      5      7:11:10   7:35:34
6       09/01/2015      6      7:11:55   7:36:51
7       09/01/2015      7      7:17:09   7:30:48
8       09/01/2015      8      7:21:33   7:37:38
9       09/01/2015      9      7:21:53   7:34:39
10      09/01/2015     10      7:22:28   7:38:32
11      09/01/2015     11      7:24:18   7:38:40
12      09/01/2015     12      7:25:08   7:39:55
13      09/01/2015     13      7:26:18   7:40:14
14      09/01/2015     14      7:26:34   7:42:21
15      09/01/2015     15      7:30:09   7:36:22
16      09/01/2015     16      7:30:24   7:42:36
17      09/01/2015     17      7:39:47   7:43:20
18      09/01/2015     18      7:46:20   7:47:22
19      09/01/2015     19      7:46:36   7:47:30
20      09/01/2015     20      7:48:46   7:49:44
```

I converted the data into POSIXlt and tried to run a nasty loop that didn't work:

```
arrival <- paste(as.character(df$Date_of_Service), as.character(df$Arrival_Time))
call <- paste(as.character(df$Date_of_Service), as.character(df$Call_Time))

arrival <- as.POSIXlt(arrival, tz="", format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
call <- as.POSIXlt(call, tz="", format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
queue <- rep(0, length(arrival))
queue[1] <- 1 

x <- 1
y <- 2
while(x < 1+length(call)){
  while(y < 1+length(arrival)){
    ifelse(difftime(call[x], arrival[y], units="secs") > 0, 
           queue[y] <- queue[y-1] + 1,
           queue[y] <- queue[y-1] - 1)
    y <- y+1
  }
  x <- x+1
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cumsum`

```
n <- 1000
start <- as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 7:30")
end <- as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 16:30")
arrival <- sort(as.POSIXct(runif(n, start, end), origin = "1970-1-1"))
waiting <- runif(n, 60, 3600)
call <- arrival + waiting
rawdata <- data.frame(
  ticket = seq_len(n),
  arrival,
  call
)

library(dplyr)
queue <- rawdata %>% 
  transmute(time = arrival, change = 1) %>% 
  bind_rows(
    rawdata %>% 
      transmute(time = call, change = -1)
  ) %>% 
  arrange(time) %>% 
  mutate(queue = cumsum(change))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(queue, aes(x = time, y = queue)) + geom_point()
```

Here is a comparison in timing between both approaches

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  jeremycg = rawdata$queue <- 1:nrow(rawdata) - sapply(rawdata$arrival, function(x){sum(x > rawdata$call)}),
  thierry = {
    queue <- rawdata %>% 
      transmute(time = arrival, change = 1) %>% 
      bind_rows(
        rawdata %>% 
          transmute(time = call, change = -1)
      ) %>% 
      arrange(time) %>% 
      mutate(queue = cumsum(change))
  }
)
```

The sorting solution is about 16 times faster for `n = 1000`

```
Unit: milliseconds
     expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval cld
 jeremycg 72.116199 75.185721 78.901888 78.772244 81.266603 114.272287   100   b
  thierry  4.512768  4.673343  5.049725  4.886944  5.065051   7.354791   100  a
```

Results for `n = 2000`. Note that the sorting solution scales much better. Sorting is now about 28 times faster.

```
Unit: milliseconds
     expr       min        lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
 jeremycg 123.12036 131.24167 140.620648 140.448737 148.017769 189.783860   100   b
  thierry   4.48925   4.72359   5.067656   4.890579   5.131761   7.064431   100  a
```

`n = 10000`

```
Unit: milliseconds
     expr       min        lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
 jeremycg 1167.0648 1185.2014 1210.70674 1205.39125 1231.09153 1304.36404   100   b
  thierry   14.9901   15.3119   16.01322   15.72178   16.53855   18.15884   100  a
```

Sorting scales clearly much better

Comment: I've added a `microbenchmark` comparison of both solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer using `sapply`.
I'm going to put the arrival and call columns on the data frame:

```
df$arrival <- paste(as.character(df$Date_of_Service), as.character(df$Arrival_Time))
df$call <- paste(as.character(df$Date_of_Service), as.character(df$Call_Time))

df$arrival <- as.POSIXlt(df$arrival, tz="", format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
df$call <- as.POSIXlt(df$call, tz="", format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Then using `sapply`, we find the total number of `calls` with a time earlier than each `arrival` (ie those that have been answered), and minus that from total calls:  `1:nrow(df)`

```
df$queue <- 1:nrow(df) - sapply(as.numeric(df$arrival), function(x) sum(x > df$call))
df$queue
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 14 15  5  1  2  1
```

Comment: This makes sense but it runs really slowly when I apply it to a data set with  3500 rows. I know sapply and variants tend to run slowly. Is there another way I can run that function?

Comment: Well, the `sapply` is used to compare each time point with each other, so it will scale poorly (`O(n^2)`). @Thierrys approach is better here - make each in a +1, each out a -1, order by time, take the cumulative sum, and subset by time in. It will scale much better, as the costliest step here is sort, which is `O(n)`

Comment: Could you explain why the time increases n^2 with your approach vs @Thierry's being n ?

Comment: You need to compare each of the n arrival times with all of the n call times. That's n times n comparisons.